# Strapi- Having issues with making AWS S3 my file upload provider

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, strapi

I'm following the directions on the Strapi site here: https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/plugins/upload.html#using-a-provider

Here is my plugin.js file located at ./config/plugins.js

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
    upload: {
      provider: 'aws-s3',
      providerOptions: {
        accessKeyId: 'id',
        secretAccessKey: 'secret',
        region: 'us-east-1',
        params: {
          Bucket: 'bucket',
        },
      },
    }
  });
```

I have strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3 installed:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "knex": "<0.20.0",
    "pg": "^8.3.2",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.0",
    "strapi": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-admin": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-connector-bookshelf": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3": "^3.1.4",
    "strapi-utils": "3.1.4"
  },
```

But when I go to my admin page on my local then go to plugins, I do not see a cog in the Media Library plugin which would allow me to change the settings.

I'm pretty stuck here, so help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is this related: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/6625

Comment: @grohjy yes this did work! I still don't see the cog next to media library, but when I upload a picture, it goes to my cloudinary account! I really hope they update their documentation soon, I saw a lot of people who were having the same issues. Link: https://medium.com/@kwinten.yc.li/strapi-set-default-file-upload-provider-to-s3-cloudinary-rackspace-5b8ef6f61daa

Answer (score 7):

For Strapi V3

The Strapi upload plugin documentation has an error.
https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/upload.html#enabling-the-provider

Going by their docs' config code, I did not have functioning S3 upload; it would always upload locally.

Now my working S3 provider config looks like below. Essentially you just remove the `config: { }` sub-wrapper that their docs specify; it looks like it's not needed.

Doing this, I was able to upload media files through Strapi Dashboard (Plugins/Media Library), and the files would appear in my S3. Another indicator its working is it takes longer than local upload. Upload api list route works and shows my file URLs as full S3 urls.

**config/plugins.js**

```
upload: {
    provider: 'aws-s3',
    providerOptions: {
        accessKeyId: env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        secretAccessKey: env('AWS_ACCESS_SECRET'),
        region:  env('AWS_REGION'),
        params: {
            Bucket: env('AWS_BUCKET')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The above config is valid for [Strapi v3](https://docs-v3.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/upload.html#using-a-provider), while the config from the link is compatible with [Strapi v4](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/plugins/upload.html#using-a-provider). So most likely you were trying to configure the plugin for Strapi v3 with the config from v4.

Comment: omggg thank you, this helped me realize I was using Strapi v4 compatible version of the plugin, "@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3", when I was still on Strapi v3 and should have been using "strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3", which does indeed not have the `config: {}` wrapping object

Answer (score 4):

For AWS, update `~/extensions/upload/config/settings.json` file with below code to make it work:

```
{  
    "provider": "aws-s3",  
    "providerOptions": {
      "accessKeyId": "keyId",
      "secretAccessKey": "key",
      "region": "region",
      "params": {
        "Bucket": "bucket"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

made these changes worked for me, and its the best way to use env variables instead of hard coded values:
edit file config/plugin.js:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
upload: {
  provider: 'aws-s3'
  },
});
```

create a file extensions/upload/config/settings.js:

```
module.exports = {
provider: 'aws-s3',
providerOptions: {
  accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
  secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_SECRET,
  region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  params: {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_NAME,
  },
},
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Pasting the following in the path ~/extensions/upload/config/settings.json worked for me:

```
{  
    "provider": "cloudinary",  
    "providerOptions": {
      "cloud_name": "Cloud Name",
      "api_key": "API Key",
      "api_secret": "Secret Key"  
   }
}
```

I still do not see the cog next to Media Library, but when I upload a picture, I see it in my cloudinary account. I really hope they update their documentation soon. This gave me a lot of trouble and I've seen a few others with this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to change any settings regarding 3rd party providers for the Media Library on the Strapi Admin. Use the `plugins.js` file for configuring the provider.

Make your configurations there (copy your `accessKeyId`, `secretAccessKey` etc. from AWS) and then any uploads made from that point should be uploaded to your specified S3 bucket on AWS.

***Side note:** it is not a good idea to store private keys like `secretAccessKey` directly in your code, make sure to use environment variables for this purpose.*

Answer (score 0):

Just be sure of having the following structure on your .config/plugins.js
In your example, you don't have the config object inside upload.

```
./config/plugins.js

module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  // ...
  upload: {
    config: {
      provider: 'aws-s3',
      providerOptions: {
        accessKeyId: env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        secretAccessKey: env('AWS_ACCESS_SECRET'),
        region: env('AWS_REGION'),
        params: {
          Bucket: env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        },
      }
    },
  },
  // ...
});
```

I hope this helps somebody, I was having the same issue and it was just that the config was missing inside the upload.

Saludos!