# Strapi doesn't upload media files to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, media, strapi

I have trouble with configuring the `@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3` plugin correctly I think...
I have an ECS container that's running a strapi instance. I have a media library in strapi and I want to connect it to my S3 bucket, so I will be able to upload media files to the bucket.

I have followed the [official documentation](https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-set-up-amazon-s3-upload-provider-plugin-for-our-strapi-app), but to no avail. No matter how I played with the configuration nothing worked...

I'm corrently using strapi version `4.11.7`.
Here is the plugin configuration from `config/plugin.ts`:

```js
export default ({ env }) => ({
    upload: {
        config: {
            provider: "strapi-provider-upload-aws-s3",
            providerOptions: {
                accessKeyId: env("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"),
                secretAccessKey: env("AWS_ACCESS_SECRET"),
                region: env("AWS_REGION"),
                params: {
                    ACL: env("AWS_ACL", "public-read"),
                    signedUrlExpires: env("AWS_SIGNED_URL_EXPIRES", 15 * 60),
                    Bucket: env("BUCKET_NAME"),
                },
            },
            actionOptions: {
                upload: {},
                uploadStream: {},
                delete: {},
            },
        },
    },
});
```

and I also added the following middleware edit in `config/middlewares.ts`:

```js
export default [
    "strapi::errors",
    {
        name: "strapi::security",
        config: {
            contentSecurityPolicy: {
                useDefaults: true,
                directives: {
                    "connect-src": ["'self'", "https:"],
                    "img-src": [
                        "'self'",
                        "data:",
                        "blob:",
                        "dl.airtable.com",
                        "*.amazonaws.com",
                    ],
                    "media-src": [
                        "'self'",
                        "data:",
                        "blob:",
                        "dl.airtable.com",
                        "*.amazonaws.com",
                    ],
                    upgradeInsecureRequests: null,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    "strapi::cors",
    "strapi::poweredBy",
    "strapi::logger",
    "strapi::query",
    "strapi::body",
    "strapi::session",
    "strapi::favicon",
    "strapi::public",
];
```

When I upload the files (sending `POST /upload`) I get `200 OK`. I opened up the response body, and I saw that the provider is set to `local`:

```json
[
    {
        "id": 18,
        "name": "image.jpg",
        "alternativeText": null,
        "caption": null,
        "width": null,
        "height": null,
        "formats": null,
        "hash": "image",
        "ext": ".jpg",
        "mime": "image/jpeg",
        "size": 257.18,
        "url": "/uploads/image.jpg",
        "previewUrl": null,
        "provider": "local",
        "provider_metadata": null,
        "folderPath": "/",
        "createdAt": "2023-08-30T11:07:34.597Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-08-30T11:07:34.597Z"
    }
]
```

I think it will might connect to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63560953/strapi-having-issues-with-making-aws-s3-my-file-upload-provider/70749595#70749595), but I don't quite sure...

Here is what I see in strapi's admin panel:
[admin.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFtwD.png)

Here is what I see in AWS management console:
[console.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YlGN.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: did you find a solution